# data structure for time series analysis in Java Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, time-series, electron

I am working on a electron / node.js app, which reads in time series data from excel files and do some analysis with the time series data. It may sound odd to process large time series data with Javascript.

The time series data may contain up to millions of records.

The data structure I am currently using is an array of objects, looks like:

```
var data = [{
            Time: , //a Date() value, the time stamp
            psi: //a number, the pressure value at the time
            }, ...]
```

Operation to the time series data includes:

- copy,
- smooth the data,
- delete some points,
- bisection (given a time stamp, find the location in the array),
- find local maximum/minimum within a time range,
- calculate average pressure values within a time range
- etc.

The current array of object may prone to some issues. I saw some was suggesting use two separate array to store time stamp and pressure separately.

Just wondering, from **speed / robustness** point of view, what's a good data structure for processing time series in Javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your motivation. Are you trying to find a datastructure that would be the _most efficient when iterating_ the array? Or are you looking for efficient algorithms for doing those operations? And is the data already sorted according to the timestamp?

Comment: I am trying to find the data structure that are robust to do those operations. not the algorithm. yes, the data already sorted by the time stamps. @MerveSahin

Comment: "*some was suggesting use two separate array*" - it's called [parallel array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array). Whether this is actually easier to work with and more efficient/faster, you will have to try out and benchmark. We can't really tell whether it is appropriate in your situation.